# How to eliminate newline inside json into one line?

Tags: postgresql

pg12, have this function to extract only text created by Quill Editor:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.fun(
    j json)
    RETURNS text
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' immutable
AS $BODY$
begin
  return string_agg((obj->>'insert') || ' ', '')
  FROM json_array_elements(j->'ops') obj;
end;
$BODY$;
```

`select * from fun('{"ops":[{"insert":"1st line\n."},{"insert":"2nd line."},{"insert":"333"}]}')` returns

[image]

`return string_agg(replace((obj->>'insert')::text, '\n', '') || ' ', '')` won't do the trick.

How to achieve?
**1st line. 2nd line. 333**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the function `replace()`.

```sql
...
begin
  return string_agg(replace(obj->>'insert', e'\n', '') || ' ', '')
...
```

From [the documentation:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS)

> PostgreSQL also accepts “escape” string constants, which are an extension to the SQL standard. An escape string constant is specified by writing the letter E (upper or lower case) just before the opening single quote, e.g., E'foo'.